# Can't add SendGrid account to azure subscription

Tags: azure, sendgrid

When I add new SendGrid account, on the last step "*Review legal terms*", It shows me an error message "*We were unable to get information for your resources*" and I cannot submit the form. What's wrong?

I'm an administrator and owner of the subscription.

[image]

Comment: Just tried it myself and I _was_ able to complete the 'Legal terms' step and add a SendGrid account. Which region are you in? Did you try to contact [AzureSupport on Twitter](https://twitter.com/azuresupport)? They're actually quite fast. Also: please open the debugger tools in your browser (F12) and see if there's any errors in there.

Comment: I'm in Poland. No I didn't  try to contact them.

Comment: I see that there is an error on AJAX call to: 

BUbKUXDk0t3l.js:formatted:5860 POST https://s2.billing.ext.azure.com/api/Billing/Subscription/GetSpecsCosts 0 ()
muYoLbL5A_ZL.js:6 [Microsoft_Azure_Billing]  10:23:03 AM GetSpecsCost GetSpecsCost: Failed to get spec cost information for subscriptionId aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa, specResourceSets [{"id":"productpurchase::0","thirdParty":[{"id":"productpurchase::0","publisherId":"Sendgrid","offerId":"sendgrid_azure","planId":"free","promotionCode":"","meters":[]}],"firstParty":[]}] and specsToAllowZeroCost ["productpurchase::0"].

Comment: Is there any error code?